# Searching in Solr

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, solr

I am building an ecommerce project where I am using solr search engine.I want to search based on specific keyword. If I enter "c1234" , it should display all the documents having keyword "c1234". Its working fine. But, if I enter "c12#34" then also it should consider "c1234" only. So the problem is I want to ignore the hash tag here. Solr should not consider my hash tag and it should display the same result for both the cases.

The other problem is I want to trim whitespaces. If I search "HP 940", it should trim the whitespace and should display the similar result as "HP940". So I want to have similar reults to be displayed with or without the whitespace. For example, if I enter "Hp 940", solr should consider it as "HP940". So the problem is triming the white spaces

Comment: Which solr connector in Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it before Requesting Solr, in PHP level you may trim the search text, and remove special chars such as the '#' etc.
If you're using some extention you can just rewrite the query preparation part.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems you're describing. First, you want to search for two 'words' that are very similar (c1234, c12#34). Second, you want to search for two words that should be a single word.

The first problem can be solved in Solr using fuzzy matching. In effect, you're asking the search engine to treat two different words as 'close enough'. You could also solve this problem by using an ngram field, which will split each word into multiple pairs of letters (truck becomes tr,ru,uc,ck), and this can help deal with misspellings (if you have a lot of data, this approach can be more performant).

For the second problem, you are trying to do something called 'decompounding' (take two words and make them one, e.g., 'bat man' should be 'batman'). There are two ways you can solve this, one easy but annoying, the other hard, error-prone, and pretty expert-level stuff.

The easy way is to use a synonyms file. For common word pairs you'd like to decompound, you can add an entry. This will treat every occurrence of two words as if they were one word. You can do this either a query-time, which would turn your user's search into one word to match what's in your catalog, or at index-time, which would add words to your catalog to make them findable by one-word queries.

The other way to solve this is to auto-decompound, which requires a plugin in Solr that can recognize common compound word forms and take action to decompound them, often with support from synonym files as well.